# How does editing work?

Tags: support, faq, edits

It is possible for users to edit an existing post.

- How do edits work?
- Who may edit a question or answer?
- How can you tell what has been changed between edits?

> For more information, see "[Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing)" in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)

**Related:** [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 95):

[image: "edit button"]

### How do edits work?

Users can edit the questions and answers submitted to the site. This gives the site a *wiki* feel and allows the information to constantly evolve and remain up to date.  Those users who are allowed to edit a post can do so by clicking the *edit* link associated with that post.

Multiple edits made by the same person may be combined into a single revision, if they occur within a short period of time (currently 5 minutes), unless the post is later edited by someone else or one of the events listed at the bottom occurs. Edits made by the original author are considered part of the base revision if submitted within 5 minutes of posting (again, unless someone else edits the post or one of those events occurs) or migrating. This [does not apply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378754/377214) if the user doesn't have the [remove new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) privilege (awarded at 10 reputation on all sites) - edits from these users will always create a new revision.

It is possible to “rollback” changes made in a revision. This can be done during editing by selecting a previous revision to edit from the dropdown, but can also be accomplished via the "rollback" link displayed on previous revisions within the revision history list. This action will earn you a bronze "Cleanup" badge when first used.

When multiple editors submit binding changes, the last one in “wins”, regardless of who began editing first. Both revisions are preserved however, and changes lost can be restored either by rolling back to the previous revision or by manually copying text into a new revision.

To promote good edits, a user who suggests an edit to someone else’s post will get +2 reputation points when that edit suggestion is approved. You do not get the reputation bonus for binding edits, whether this is because you are editing your own post, you are editing a community wiki post and have the [edit community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) privilege, or you have the [edit questions and answers](/help/privileges/edit) privilege. Also, you are limited to a maximum of 1000 reputation points earned from edits, and reputation earned from suggested edits counts toward the daily reputation limit of 200.

### Who may edit a question or answer?

The original author of a question or answer may edit their own post.  Additionally, users with the [edit questions and answers](/privileges/edit) privilege may edit any question or answer.  The one exception is locked posts, which may only be edited by moderators, including the original author, until they are unlocked.  Additionally, the amount of reputation needed to edit *community wiki* posts is [much lower](/privileges/edit-community-wiki) than that needed to edit ordinary questions and answers. If a user does not have enough reputation to edit directly, they can still suggest an edit (see a related FAQ question, [How do suggested edits work?](/q/76251)).

### How can you tell what has been changed between edits?

#### Edit indicator

Once your question has been edited, there will be a note of it, with the time since the last edit hyperlinked to a revision history for the post.

Example:

> [image: Edit indicatior]

#### Revision history

Each revision is displayed in a separate, collapsible section. Older revisions start out already collapsed. If a comment was specified by the person editing, that will be displayed in yellow next to the revision number; otherwise, the total number of characters added or removed in that revision will be listed, as well as whether the title and tags have been changed (questions only). Once expanded, the revision will be displayed, with changes highlighted.

The edit link on older revisions lets you copy that edition to a new revision, essentially letting you roll back to that revision and edit it at the same time.

Example:

> [image: revision history item]

##### Revision diff color key:

- *Green background*: characters added
- *Red text + <strike>strikeout</strike>*: characters removed

#### Grace period

In order to prevent a series of tiny edits from showing up in the revision history, a single user who makes a binding (not suggested) edit to a post is given a 5-minute [grace period](/tags/grace-period/info), *except* if one of the following conditions is true:

- The previous revision was a rollback.
- The new revision is a rollback (includes cases where one selects to edit a prior revision and doesn't make any changes).
- The user does not have the [remove new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) privilege.

During this period, any additional edits they make are collapsed into the same edit in the revision history, displaying only the final outcome of all their edits within that 5-minute period. The grace period ends after exactly 5 minutes, or if:

- Another user edits the post, at which time *their* grace period begins.
- A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor (ignores deleted comments).
- If the post being edited is a question and an answer has been added since the previous revision (ignores deleted answers but *does* include answers by the editor).
- The post is a question, and it has been closed since the previous revision.

Comment: Right now, it's 5 minutes from the first edit. That is subject to change however, and should not be relied on - still beta...

Comment: @clahey: that definition is best left to The Main FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq), where presumably it will always be up-to-date.

Comment: @unknown: read the site FAQ - editing of other user's posts is very much a core part of SO. If abuse happens, you can 1) rollback the change with a single click, and 2) flag for moderator attention to let someone know what's going on.

Comment: Is this the currently live wiki? If so, it does not mention that things can get awkward of there is an edit by a lower rep use in progress, indicated by edit(n).

Comment: Assume if someone has done a useless edit on my answer which is edit number 5. So this last edit doesn't have a `rollback` but my own last edit which is number 4. So does it mean that if I click on the rollback on edit 4, that answer will set back into edit 4?

Comment: Yes, @boncodigo

Comment: Where goes the line between being better to suggest the original author to edit, or doing the edit yourself? Especially if I am a low rep user?

Comment: @Shog9 Can you confirm that this entry is up-to-date (as well as confirm the correctness of my recent edit)? It seems the last significant update was made around July '13; I would do it myself but I am not sure if or how the system has changed since then.

Comment: Looks fine, @JasonC. If you're not aware of any changes, that's probably because there haven't been any.

Comment: @Shog9 By that logic, 12 hours ago, the grace period changes probably didn't exist.

Comment: @JasonC I was unaware of  `A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor.`, that's interesting, +1

Comment: I’m under the impression that editing is done for the sake of editing sometimes. Is there some reputation bonus or incentive to edit maybe a virtual badge that is to be won? I’ve been checking the editing done on users and it’s not always warranted. There are inconsistencies by the same editing moderator. It’s actually intrusive and high handed to constantly leave your mark on every question. Some editing is clearly necessary but certainly not all and it’s most odd when one time it’s done one way and another the exact opposite. It’s like HOA reps getting high on their artificial power

Comment: Let's say there there is a **1 character** typo in my original question code sample.  Someone answers the question and includes that typo.  I fix the original question and want to edit the answer to match.  How can someone do that when there is a minimum of 6 characters edited before an edit can be saved .

Comment: Find 5 of that author's own 1 character typos, @steve. Or a 3 character typo and a two-character typo. Or a 5 character typo. ...you get the idea.

Comment: @Shog9 or just make a random edit, which is what i did, but it defeats the purpose of the idea behind minimum edit length.

Comment: @Catija regarding your recent edit in rev 26, could it be that removal of grace period opens for malicious users a way to flood / DoS the site by multiple fast changes all of which will make a way into a post revisions history? Checking [rate limits guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/165773) made me feel that system currently won't throttle stuff like that

Comment: @gnat I'm not sure. It's a site setting, so we're able to pretty quickly disable it if it becomes an issue. For right now, the bigger issue is the real spam wave on SO that we're trying to quash.

Comment: Is it also possible to add the number of edits to own post per day/hour/minute for users without the "restrictions lifted" privilege to rate-limits, @Catija? Would you like a feature request if this sounds like a good idea? I don't see any valid use cases for allowing unlimited edits on own posts when pretty much everything else is rate-limited (I can be wrong - will make a SEDE query when I have time).

Comment: @Catija disabling this would mean opening site for spammers tricks. I would suggest instead to just add some throttling to consequtive edits of the same post by <10 users, this will take care of any undesirable side effects. Something like 10 edits per minute, 20 edits per hour, 30 edits a day would probably suffice to keep system safe no matter what else you would want to change in the editing features

Comment: If one of y'all want to create a request for that, go for it - it seems like a reasonable solution. I can talk to someone next week about how big of a risk it is to see if we need to prioritize it.

Comment: Will do, @Catija, unless ninja'd. Some prior research needs to be done first, but my gut tells me it's unlikely that it will turn out that there are legit low rep users making more than 1-5 edits per hour to their own posts.

Comment: As I expected, the [max number of edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1593985/top-100-posts-by-number-of-edits-made-in-the-hour-of-post-existence?Hours=1) (including grace period edits) made in the 1st hour of post's existence (non-deleted only, but it's precisely what the query was about - to check if the effect of such a rate limit would be widespread) is 15. Makes sense to limit consequent edits by post author to somewhere around this number (actually, I feel like *everyone* should be limited - there's no reason to spout edits). Will expand in the FR. cc @Catija

Comment: [done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378737/786798), @Catija

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine But, the data you got from SEDE *can't* tell you how many grace period edits were made on those posts, so there's no way to know how many edits there *actually* were. What's recorded there is only edits by the same person which are more than 5 minutes apart, or edits by someone other than the prior editor (and rollbacks). So, while it is interesting data, it's not actually how many edits were made to the post.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Ahhh... it looks like Shog9 already covered that in an answer [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378755/271271).

Comment: yup, @Makyen, just had a conversation with Shog9 about that :) To be precise, it wasn't my intention to gauge exactly how many edits were made but rather how many revisions were made in the first hour of post's existence (so, not ideal wording on my part). It would, of course, be ideal to be able to get a precise number were it possible, but alas.  I do expect that the actual number of edits may be marginally or significantly higher with grace edits. Interesting what the query will show on Monday

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Yeah, I'm interested to see what it says on Monday, but it will be even better in another week (and, obviously, continuing to improve as time goes on). The change has really only been active for the lowest SE Network use days, so the information will be limited, but the data from the next SEDE DB copy should at least give some hints.

Comment: Yeah, the query started to [pick up](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72239260/timeline) the newly made posts, but let's see how it goes this week. So far I see only 2 posts with 10+ revisions by new users, but that number should grow - curious about the next week too.