# I edited a question at least twice, but there doesn't seem to be any edit history

Tags: support, edits, grace-period

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

When I view this answer...

[How do I execute some code in a superclass after all the subclasses have been constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747182/how-do-i-execute-some-code-in-a-superclass-after-all-the-subclasses-have-been-con/2747280#2747280)

...I don't see any way to view the edit history. I know I edited it at least a couple times.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work
(if your edits all fall in the grace period, they won't create individual revisions)

Comment: @Shog9, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

All edits made within a 5 minute period are condensed into one "revision". So, the first five minutes of your post are free for you to edit it as much as you need to. Which sounds short but 5 minutes is actually enough to get quite a few quick edits. For subsequent edits, all edits within 5 minutes of the first marking are condensed into that revision. The comments for all such revisions are concatenated together, but the "edit body" is going to be the whole of it all.

Comment: Okay, thanks, so it sort of resembles the grace period for editing comments. I thought something like that might be going on, but I hadn't ever noticed before.