# Why do people keep editing my questions?

Tags: discussion, edits

Very often after I ask a new question on SO, and I see someone has edited my question.

English is not my first language but I try not to make mistakes and keep my questions well formatted. So how can I see the changes?

- Why do they do it?
- Do they get easy reputation for this?

Comment: @Georg http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64082/why-do-people-keep-editing-my-questions :p

Comment: @DrDro: Originally it was about people editing and he *"can't see any changes"*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does editing work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do they get easy reputation for this?

[Yes if they have less than 2000 rep and suggest an edit and it is accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68636/does-editing-a-question-or-an-answer-decrease-reputation), otherwise No. They also can earn [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges). [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor), [Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor), and [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) being among them.

> can I see what did they edit?

Yes. If you click on the date & time next to the edited text that made the edit, it will show you the revision history. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3683451/revisions).

Comment: They actually do a good job, I wouldn't waste my time on adding question mark to someone's question title, thank you good people))))

Comment: Waiting for someone to add a question mark on this question and we will be done.

Comment: @Burjua: I gotta ask, what's with all the extra ")"s ?

Comment: @gnos, Yeah, I was wondering that too.

Comment: @gnostradamus: I'd assume that @Burjua is from Russia -- Russians often use multiple ')'s in a row as a shorthand for multiple smilies.  Unfortunately, it's a regionalism (something only used in one place) that can be very confusing to everyone not from Russia.

Answer (score 10):

**Why?**

They edit the question so that the ones who are reading it understand it better and faster.

**Badges?**

Yes, bronze, silver and gold. But it will be childish to believe they are doing it out of sheer competition.

Comment: I have a strange feeling about why this answer has as many votes ...

Comment: I simply do this - last time, I edited your "i"-s to "I"-s in gamedev - for the sake to not letting something bad, which can be made better. But I won't make free work for the SE Inc until I live. So, the compromise between these motivations that I do this until I get my golden badge for this work.

Comment: lemme guess, your ban isn't working properly @peterh

Comment: @Telkitty Let me guess, now you think you are harassing me.