# Does editing a question or an answer decrease reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Just wondering does editing your own question/answer cause reputation loss?

Yes or No?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not have editing privileges, you may gain 2 reputation for suggesting an edit to another person's post if it is accepted.  Otherwise, you neither gain nor lose reputation for editing posts.

However, **editing is encouraged** to make the site's content better, and is rewarded by a whole slew of badges ([Cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/4/cleanup), [Copy Editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/65/copy-editor), [Editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor), [Organizer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer), [Strunk & White](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white), [Tag Editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/73/tag-editor), and [Taxonomist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist)).

There are many good posts on editing guidelines here on Meta, so search around for that if you need additional help.

Comment: I can't believe this answer got accepted, that is not what the OP asked, what is wrong with this world??S!??!?S?1?

Comment: Editing your own answer or question enough times will change it to Community Wiki. Doesn't this cause reputation loss (visible when a recalc happens)?

Comment: @Peter: Votes from before the post was converted to CW still count toward the owner's reputation.

Answer (score 7):

No

Comment: I would add that you are encouraged to edit your question/answer to clarify it and make it better.