# Get reputation by editing question?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68636/does-editing-a-question-or-an-answer-decrease-reputation), there should be no reputation gained for editing posts. But I got 2 rep points for editing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974121/how-to-resolve-no-data-type-for-node-error-in-hibernate).

Is it a bug?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You stumbled upon the [suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/suggested-edits/info) feature.

See: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: I got it now, thanks. I can't believe that this functions has been released for 2 months!