# How much rep do I need to edit others' posts on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

From time to time, I notice some imperfections (e.g. misspellings, usage of incorrect words — which can be replaced with synonyms to make questions much more understandable — and inconsistent tagging) in question/post text. Sometimes I am in a constructive mood and wouldn't mind contributing as an editor. How many reputation points do I need to be able to do so?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) you need 2000 Reputation to edit other people's postings.

Comment: Or 100 if the posts are marked as "Community Wiki".

Answer (score 3):

Here's the list of the reputation you need for each modification on SO :

- Community-Wiki Post : 100 reputations
- Tag : 500 reputations
- Non Community-Wiki Post : 2000 reputations

**Note :** The reputation can change from a site to an other, always refer to the FAQ for the exact value.

**Extra Note:** When you retag a question, you may want to create a completly new tag which requires 1500 reputations.

Comment: Nitpicky -1. Normally, retagging only takes 500 rep, as you say... but you now need 1500 to create a new tag.

Comment: @Popular Creating a new tag is a different task than editing the list of existing tag.

Comment: whoa, "Hox." And yeah, it's different, unless you're editing the list _to include a new tag_.

Comment: @Popular I had to do a monthly name change, I couldn't resist :p

Comment: +2 (don't get to say that very often)