# How do I edit others' questions?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much rep do I need to edit others' posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66455/how-much-rep-do-i-need-to-edit-others-posts-on-stack-overflow)

How do I edit other users' questions or tags? Is there any reputation requirement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/abilities

Comment: @radp, huh, when'd they roll that widget out?

Comment: @Pop: waffles deployed it [a few days ago](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/210529#210529).

Comment: @radp - if you click for a description of the abilities it's a little... lacking. :)

Comment: @Jon B: I think they're wiki - I get an [edit wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/abilities/edit-wiki/17) link on meta but not on SO.

Comment: waffles set it so anyone with 2000 rep on meta can edit them, and then they're going to get mirrored everywhere else once they're all written

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a reputation limit.  You need 2000 reputation to edit regular posts and 500 to retag, or 100 to edit posts marked [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow).  See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the SE site you are talking about. For SO the answer is given, with 2000 to edit other peoples' questions and 100 for cw. Yet other sites, even depending on there stage in live, have other requirements.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) for the numbers. And the widget SE-site\abilities that @radp pointed out works on all sites.