# When would I be able to edit other users' questions?

Tags: support, edit-rights

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

I see others editing my questions and I sometimes want to edit errors/mistakes in others' questions too. But I can't do that now.

When would I be able to edit other users' questions? What is the required reputations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/privileges

If you look next to the "edit questions and answers" link on the right hand side you will see a percentage. That indicates how far you have to go.

If you click on the link it will show that you require 2000 rep to have this privilege.

Comment: +1 for explaining how to find the answer.