# Fictional edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

Just to make it clear I really love spending time here.

Is there any reason why many posts are getting edited by non-authors soon after they are posted with almost no visible change?

I want to believe that these fictional edits are not just for give-me-that-600-edits-badge which would mean that Stack Overflow's driving force is pure vanity, but on the other hand there's no such a thing as free lunch, so I guess, either people get badges and credits for what they did, including ridiculous edits, or Q&A service won't be able to exist in the current shape.

Comment: Can we see an example of these fictional edits?

Comment: There's plenty , but I do not want to point at particular individuals as such, I'd rather point at the whole phenomenon which I believe is not hard to notice

Comment: @matcheek - are you sure that it isn't tags that are being modified?

Comment: Two users making the same edit (fixing spelling) could be colliding. This would mean the 2nd users edits would be apparently non-existent.

Comment: 99% or maybe some white spaces were added, but definitely not tags

Comment: @ChrisF: that's a good point

Comment: Without an example, this is extremely difficult to answer.

Comment: @Rebecca: I do not really want to point at individuals. Did anybody notice such a practice taking place?

Comment: @matcheek are you referring to *minor corrections* like the one I did to this post? Or edits where nothing meaningful is changed at all? If the latter, please show examples. I've not seen that happening as a widespread practice

Comment: @Pekka: I've been looking for some edits you just did, but couldn't find any, without revision control system at hand it's not apparent. What are these edits?

Comment: @matcheek He changed "is" to "are" and "exists" to "exist" ( [revision 2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/72135/revisions) )

Comment: @matcheek fixed some spelling errors, just to prove the point that minor edits are okay when they serve a purpose. Some people will edit typos and such when they see them - I usually don't, but I don't think there's anything wrong with doing that in principle. It would be different with *completely meaningless* edits, but as said, I haven't seen many of those

Comment: @matcheek Click on the time where it says 'Edited X minutes ago'. You'll see all the changes.

Comment: @Tyler: didn't now we've got such a feature accessible for all, blimey

Comment: @matcheek Click the triangle in the revision history to expand the revision

Comment: [Read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Comment: still on a steep learning curve! I thought revision controls were for admins' eyes exclusively. Don't really want to hunt anybody doing that, but now I could check that easily without much hassle.

Comment: Hmm...I've been on a pseudo-tag killing rampage again, and have been deleting politese and fixing and spelling or grammar errors I catch as I go. Most of these are pretty minor edits, but I always (well, almost always) leave an editing explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless

- someone keeps editing and editing for no apparent reason (e.g. just to force the post to be CW),
- two people start an edit war over whether it's called "Javascript" or "JavaScript" (with the third guy voting for "ECMAScript" just around the corner), or
- they actually change the *meaning* of the post,

I don't see a problem. If some minor corrections improve the post, why not? As the FAQ says, it's <s>kinda like</s> <s>sorta like</s> bearing a certain resemblance to Wikipedia.

And since you don't want to point to any specific examples, this theoretical statement is all I can give.

Comment: The fool!  ECMAScript is completely different from JavaScript!

Comment: @Aarobot: You mean "from Javascript".

Comment: so not true. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript

Comment: @Pekka: oh come on, you just edited that Wikipedia page right now

Comment: bwahahaha! I edited it years ago expecting *this specific moment!*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what small edits other people do, but about the only thing I edit for is obvious typos (and not capitalization, either, actual mis-spellings). I do that about once or twice a month.

Are you sure you're seeing this behavior from a small group of people? Or are you actually seeing a lot of different people touching up the spelling/grammar of other's posts once or twice a week?