# Possible to see what's changed when another user edits your question?

Tags: discussion, questions, users, edits

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

If one of my questions says it was edited by another user, is there a way I can see what changes that user has made? Also, does that mean that question has become a CW?

Comment: See: [How does editing work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) and also [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is - at the bottom of your question, it will state that the question has been edited and the time that it was edited.

**Simply click on the time to see the edits made to the question.**

[image]

To answer your other question, no - the question does not necessarily become CW. Details about CW questions can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can click on the part that says "Edited N minutes ago" and it will show the edit history of your question.

It does not necessarily mean that it has become a community wiki, however after a certain number of edits (10 total, or by 6 different editors, I believe), it will automatically become CW.