# Is it possible to edit a question title once asked?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Apologies if I've missed an obvious button, but I cant for the life of me figure out how to change the title of a question I've asked on SO.

If it's not possible then it should be a feature request so the OP can rephrase / avoiding potentially embarrassing typos!

Comment: You did miss something obvious. The [edit] link.

Comment: Yes it is. Its the edit link. In fact I just edited this question's title to remove the extraneous single quote you put in the title

Comment: Thanks! I'd edited a question body text before but totally missed the ability to edit the title!

Comment: You can always [edit] your post.  We like [edit]ing so much, there is specific markup in comments that creates a link to edit the commented post--`[edit]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an edit link towards the bottom of the question, right under the tags:

[image: Screenshot showing location of edit link]

On the edit page, you can edit the title in the text box at the top:

[image: Screenshot showing location of title edit text box]