# Editing doesn't change the question

Tags: support, edits

I have seen an answer to a question on Stack Overflow.

> > [image: Question - normal]

It contains a typo, so it is edited.

> > [image: Question - editing]

The editing shows that it should be fixed, but it isn't.

Link to answer: [sticky div in sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418983/sticky-div-in-sidebar/9419020#answer-9419020)

I cleared my cache, cookies etc. and then reloaded the page, same thing

**EDIT:** I went to my friend's house and it wasn't visible on her computer either

Thank you.

Comment: So you still see `#` in front of the selectors in the actual answer view? But on the revisions page, it shows the fixed version? Also, note that you clear your cache, etc, etc, because people are bound to tell you to do that.

Comment: The typo being `#sidebar` -> `.sidebar`? I see it fixed now with no edit history. I'd guess the original user fixed it at the same time as you, the edit controller registered your submit as a no-change edit and so left your view as the pre-edit version?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @user986276 Seems like a good question to me... there are tons of legitimate questions like this that get downvoted so don't feel bad about it... my experience has been that people here on meta tend to be extremely trigger happy with the downvotes.

Comment: Downvotes mean something different here on Meta. This is described in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). (cc @Brandon) For example, I downvoted because I can't repro the bug. The tag has since been removed, but I still don't think it makes much sense as a support question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it was my ISP doing some aggressive caching.

I switched to another ISP and now it edits the way it should.

Answer (score 4):

Chain of events:

- You loaded the page.
- You saw that the edit had `#` instead of `.`.
- Sometime before you clicked edit, Purmou used his 5-minute grace period to fix the answer.
- You clicked the edit button.
- The system loaded the now-present version of the post, which uses the `.` instead.

Simply reloading the page should bring up what it actually is. Users are always granted a 5-minute grace period in which they can freely edit their post without it being marked as a separate edit.

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention that I had cleared the cache, cookies, blah, blah then reloaded the page. Editing now.

Answer (score 1):

When a user makes a post, they have a 5 minute window in which they can make edits without them being listed explicitly - they will all appear as one final (possibly awesome) post.

What possibly happened is that you made your edit during this window and the OP caught it himself before the window closed.

You can see this post out of the [faq index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) for a complete breakdown of how the editing system works :

[How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)