# How its possible to see the different versions of an answer of a specific user?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

I am involved in a question, and an answer was edited three times. Is there a way to see the earlier versions of an answer? I mean is there something like cache  in SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the answer was edited within the first 5 minutes of posting then you will only see the last version.  This is a grace period of editing after posting an answer.

If the edits were made after the grace period, all the changes are saved and can be viewed by clicking the timestamp in the user card underneath the post.

Take *your* post for example :

[image]

You can see that @gnat made an edit on your question.

If the original poster makes additional edits, only the timestamp will be displayed;
Just like in my answer -

[image]

You'll be able to see all the edits that were made on that post, **who** made them, **what the edits were** and **how long ago** they occurred.

This view is available for questions and answers alike!

---

For further reading you can consult this post from the [FAQ] related to editing :
[How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link that says it has been edited.

[image]

Comment: What's up with those "timeline" and "history" links?

Comment: @slh - possibly [this script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) or something similar..

Comment: @slhck: (No longer) secret magic! Timeline is pretty useful if you can read it as its gives a very good overview, history are just the edits. You definitely should check it out...