# What's the purpose of editing old revisions?

Tags: support, edits, revisions-list

I noticed that I can edit old revisions of a question. I don't want to use that feature just to learn what it's good for.

What's the purpose of that?

- Can I beautify older revisions?
- Can I mangle the edit history (like [Git's rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing))?

PS: I'm mainly active on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/about) and also quite new to the site. This is a general meta question, so I ask here.

Comment: In short: unless you mean to Rollback to that revision, **don't do that** (Longer answer is already posted and accepted)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you edit an old revision, it'll be copied *over* the current revision and becomes the new version of the post. It is a shortcut to rollback+edit.

I would have pointed you to [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) but at the time of your question this particular information was not there yet; I've added it in.

Comment: Well, it's there now. :)

Comment: /me whistles innocently.

Comment: Yep I know - but now your last sentence is not relevant. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: There, made your comment irrelevant instead. :-)