# How to edit questions without having to be peer-reviewed?

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

I'm asking whether I can edit posts without having my edit to be *peer-reviewed*? I thought this will happen when my reputation reaches +1500. But I still have my edit to be *peer-reviewed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Stack overflow, this requires 2000 rep: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit

You can view the Privileges on any SE site and see the amount of rep needed (not sure if they are all the same).

Comment: The beta sites have a lower threshold - [1000 points](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit)