# Not receiving +2 for edits anymore

Tags: support, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

When I reformat the code in or otherwise improve someone else's post, the edit goes up for approval. Under the condition that it's judged as appropriate change (which it usually is), the said post gets updated (which is good for the community) and I receive +2 reputation (which is fun for me).

For some reason, the latter part isn't working anymore. I make the edits (which by itself **is indeed** important) but the +2 doesn't make it to my account.

One explanation would be that my **all** edits are deemed unsatisfactory (but that's highly unlikely). Another one would be that it's a bug (but that's even more unlikely).

What am I missing?

Comment: You hit 2,000 reputation points. Edits only give +2 for the first 2,000 points. Now you no longer gain points for edits, but you can edit whatever you want without having to wait for approval.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was looking for an answer to my question without finding it so I guess it might be good idea to keep **my** question because of the title - for searching purposes. What do you think?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: That's what usually happens when a question is closed as a duplicate. It's not deleted *because* it can lead people looking for different keywords, to the intended canonical post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Congratulations! You now have 2000+ reputation. Now you don't need to suggest edits any longer, because you can directly edit any post. See [Edit questions and answers privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I noticed that my editions go through directly but I assumed that others were **very** quick to approve them (because they're so great, haha). Now that I think about it, I realize that I also was allowed into approving other's editions and such. Cool! So, what do I get reputation for now (except the obvious - helping others/myself)?!

Comment: Yes. you can gain reputation by answering other's questions. Or by asking good questions.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Also, You can gain reputation by suggesting tag wiki edits. But remember, [you can only gain 1000 reputation from suggested edits.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/187824)

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Still, I think one should keep getting +2's (or at least +1's) even when "well trusted", haha. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: [Trusted users](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) can directly edit tag wiki. :)

Comment: Oh, I just saw that there's a lot of levels of trusted-ness. I ment, of course, "*trusted with editions to posts*".