# Why is there no edit time/link when the post was clearly edited?

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

This has happened to me a few times. While reading an answer, I get a message that says an edit has been made. I click the link to see the revised post. However, there is no edit time or link to see the revisions.

I've noticed that this happens when the answer was posted by someone with higher rep. I imagine that this happens because they have different editing privileges. But I want to know what changed.

Shouldn't the revision history always be visible, regardless of who makes the edits?

Comment: There is a 5 minute "grace period" for the creator of a post to edit it in. If they are the only ones that have made edits during that time, there is no edit history on the post.

Comment: See the section "grace period" in the linked dupe.