# Can I see changes to an edited answer?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

I know that if I edit my original post, I can see all the changes I've made to it, and even roll back if necessary. If someone edits their answer to my post, is there any way for me to see the original version of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just click on the 'edited' header underneath the post:

[image: edit link under a post]

Note that edits during the grace period (5 minutes after the last recorded edit) are folded into the one edit. These additions to my answer, for example, will not be shown as a separate edit.

See [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) for more details on the grace period and editing.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see that for some reason.