# Do Stack Exchange sites allow editing of comments and posts from other users?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Is this normal behavior in Stack Exchange sites that after just signing up one can edit not only his/her own comments / posts, but also others' comments / posts?

If so, then the Q&A does not look safe to me. Imagine someone maliciously modifying a post and bringing bad reputation on a Q&A member.

Can you check this and perhaps fix it?

Comment: Do you mean comments, or answers and questions?

Comment: This is a collaboratively edited Q&A (not a forum). If you don't actually mean comments, then yes, that is expected behaviour.

Comment: @PolyGeo As this is an older duplicate closed back when the Community user would edit the duplicate link into the question body upon closure, the "automatically generated text" is necessary for the dupe target to show up. It's only on newer duplicates closed after February 2013 that it shows as an automatic box.

Answer (score 14):

Only moderators can edit other users's *comments*.

However, it is true that everyone - even unregistered guests - can edit questions/answers. Those edits need to be approved by users with higher reputation though. So any malicious edits will never be shown to normal users.

Users with over 2000 reputation can edit any question or answer without approval. However, every revision is tracked in a publicly-shown history and editing "bumps" the question to the top of the "Active Questions" list, so bad edits will always be discovered and reverted.

Answer (score 5):

Questions and answers can be edited by anyone (even anonymous users).

Edits to questions and answers by people with <2000 reputation on a specific site must first be approved by the community through the review system.

Comments cannot by anyone other than the original poster of the comment (subject to a short 5 minute window). Site moderators (those with a diamond behind their name) can edit comments for an unlimited period of time.