# Can questions be renamed?

Tags: support, edits, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere. I always assumed users with extremely high reputation would be able to do this, but it doesn't appear to be the case.

Maybe I'm missing something extremely obvious though :)

Comment: Renamed? As in, given a new title?

Comment: I just did (and rolled back to preserve the original question here). What's your problem again? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yeah, but you're a shadow wizard, that doesn't count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question titles *can* be changed.  In fact, any user (even an anonymous user) can either edit a question's title or suggest an edit for a question's title.  If the user has less than 2k reputation (that number can vary on other sites) and isn't the author of that post then it needs to be approved by 2-3 other higher reputation users before it is applied.

Comment: whoops... this is absurd I can't believe I missed this. Well.. there goes my reputation :)