# Where can I find more info on editing other users posts on stackoverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits

I edited two posts so far. And I never saw my changes were accepted nor rejected. In the edit history they do not show up.

Comment: Did you see [How does editing work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)?

Comment: Just looking at your edits, I think you are lucky the first 2 weren't rejected as well.  Generally, edits that add as much to the answers as you are adding are rejected.  You should not be focusing on changing answers to add new info, but instead working on fixing grammar & spelling mistakes.  If you feel an answer is incomplete, then you can either leave a comment mentioning why you think it is incomplete, or add your own answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - There is a discrepancy between that expectation and that stated in the user interface. `We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary.`

Comment: @MartinSmith no there isn't. Between "one letter edits" and "adding new aspects to the answer" lies fixing 4 spelling mistakes, formatting the code, bringing an image inlilne, and improving grammar throughout - which is what a suggested edit should do

Comment: Ah actually on the right it does say `clarify meaning without changing it`

Comment: @KateGregory - Are these quotes from the editing guidelines that low rep users see when they click "edit"? I don't see them?

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh yes, that last quote seems clear, it was just overlaid in my mind by `please make them substantial` and from the faq `this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit and help us make it so!`

Comment: A more present `do not add new aspects` completing the `don't do one-letter-edits` would be helpful I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see all edit suggestions  you've made in your own account, [on the "activity" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505606/lester?tab=activity), with the "suggestions" filter:

[image]

It looks like you've made four suggestions. The last two have been rejected, but the first two were approved. Each link in that list goes to a page for the suggestion, which will show you the rejection reasons. Rejected suggestions don't appear in the post's revisions list because, well, they didn't make a revision and aren't part of the history.