# How can I rollback an incorrect edit made to my question?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, rollbacks

I have a [Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/575258/9461) that was edited and which caused the meaning to change.

Is there any way for me to roll back this edit without it appearing that I have edited the question?

Comment: That's a strange edit... Is it a coincidence that the editor's answer makes more sense with this drastic change of the question ? I would flag it. But only after having really checked his answer doesn't give the solution.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the fact that you edited the question?

Comment: Because if a question had votes, my editing it would allow the votes to be reconsidered and possibly changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. All edits are tracked in the revision history, except for edits during the grace period (within 5 minutes of posting).

Note that multiple edits from the same user in a short time (with no other users editing in between) will show as a single edit.

See also: [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/167443)