# How do I rollback a mistake I made editing a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, rollbacks

This is embarrassing. I was editing a long slew of code in a new poster's question by mechanically moving my mouse down line by line, but missed the fact that one of the poster's lines was so long it wrapped around. So I mechanically introduced some spaces here and introduced a bug into the code. My edit was accepted before I noticed.

What should I do in this situation? I can't see a way for me to rollback my changes. I would have liked to have been able to rollback my edit just as I can with answers. (This is not quite the same as [How can I rollback an incorrect edit made to my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174181/how-can-i-rollback-an-incorrect-edit-made-to-my-question), where it is a different person who wants to rollback.)

In the meantime I have suggested another edit, which reverses the error I made, and has some formatting to get over the 6 character barrier. If this goes through I will be rewarded for my mistake, which seems bad. (Edit: this has now gone through.)

I would like to have a feature to be able to rollback my mistaken edit. (assuming no other edits inbetween)

Comment: *robo-reviewers strike again...* Rolling it back yourself was correct (like you already have), everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: Please, please; please! Provide a link to the question/review too.

Comment: [Suggested edit no.1](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2260964) and [suggested edit no.2](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2260993)

Comment: @hayden I think more than a few non-robo-reviewers would have missed that one, especially if they're looking at rendered output rather than markdown. It's a dropped character buried amongst a load of other changes to those lines.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist good point :)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Agreed. I wasn't criticizing reviewers. I made a mistake and wanted to fix it. One interesting fact is that I got 3/4 approvals for the revision to _correct_ my mistake, which underlines my request to be able to simply rollback my own error. Nevertheless, I'd like to emphasize that with a couple of month's experience as a contributor to the site and about 10 attempted edits, I have found the reviewing to be very good. I have had several edits rejected, I have no complaints, and have learnt something from the rejections, just as I did when my answers were downvoted as a newbie.

Comment: I have edited the question that my question duplicates ("How can I cancel an edit I made on another user's answer?") to make it clear that this problem involves editing questions as well as editing answers.