# I have some questions regarding asking and answering questions

Tags: discussion

I am a new user and have some questions regarding asking and answering questions:

1. If I ask a question, which does not receive a good answer, and I solve the issue myself: how can I accept my own answer?
2. How many users can edit a question?
3. If I receive multiple answers to my question which are correct, why am I not able to accept multiple answers? I know we can use up / down votes to indicate which answers are helpful, but only Stack Overflow users would understand this. Non SO users would have little idea on how voting works here.

Comment: Okay I am waiting for all answer ! thanks @sixlettervariables

Comment: Thanks for edit @Antony . Now the question is clear !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **How do you accept your own answer?**

   You have to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer. (Source: [Accepting Answers - How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235))
2. **How many people can edit a question or answer?**

   There are no limits on the number of people who may edit a question or answer. After a certain number of edits the question or answer is converted to a Wiki. (See Also: [How does editing work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) and [What are "Community Wiki" Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts))
3. **Why can we only accept one answer?**

   Accepting a single answer allows future visitors to deduce which answer best helped the original question asker. Allowing multiple answers to be selected as the Accepted Answer would dilute the significance of an answer being chosen. You can use upvotes and/or comments to denote which answers were helpful as well. (Source: [Accepting Answers - How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235))

Comment: My 3rd question mean , Why we accept only one answer . Lot of peoples give correct answer.but why we accept only one answer ??

Comment: You can use upvotes to denote which answers were helpful as well. !!

Ya. You are good. But Its know me and you and stack over people only  .it's not know any other (Out of the SO peoples) because any other peoples  would not know the up and down vote function . Understand ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran: I don't think it takes a genius to figure out what positive or negative numbers besides an answer (or question) mean, even if one's new to the site.

Comment: You can also leave a comment which states that the answer was helpful but why you chose another answer as the Accepted Answer. A simple upvote is Ok most of the time as our users are familiar with this behavior.

Comment: Now My question are edited perfectly. now you can see the 3rd point !

Comment: @RameshRajendran What makes you think having an accepted answer is any more understandable to non-regular users than voting?  Both seem like pretty obvious indicators to me, and past experience with new users supports this assertion.