# Why not add an "It works" button

Tags: feature-request

After reading this question : [I have some questions regarding asking and answering questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177645/i-have-some-questions-regarding-asking-and-answering-questions) I was thinking that it was good to have one accepted answer, but sometimes it does not work for every body and other answer may work well too (even if they may have come too late ).

It could be great to add a small button or marker that indicate that the answer was correct or incorrect (if it happened that answer do not work).

Comment: That is what voting is for.

Comment: Of course, I haven't realise.. Should I delete the question ?

Comment: I couldn't delete it, I flagged it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It could be great to add a small button or marker that indicate that the answer was correct or incorrect (if it happened that answer do not work).

Something like this?

[image]

Comment: I think I got it =)

Comment: +1 for the hand drawn circle

Comment: I always tought it was decorative :O ! The more you know...

Answer (score 3):

That is *precicely* what the voting system is there for.  If an answer is helpful and capable of solving the given problem then you can up-vote it.  If it does not solve the problem or is otherwise unhelpful than you can down-vote the question.  Based on the net score of these community votes readers can judge the community's opinion of that answer.