# How long does it take for "edited xx yy ago" to appear?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that both answer and question, if edited by owner in a short time after posting will not show any notice. I wonder if there is such a time session which allow OP to edit his/her post without get the `edited xx yy ago` notification.

Comment: Five minutes. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work, specifically the description of the "grace period."

Comment: @DavidRobinson Great! I've been searching for this with no luck, I really apreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Five Minutes.

There is a 'grace  period' for the question owner - allowing the OP to improve the question within five minutes without pushing it towards CW.

There is also this grace period for edits that 2k users do - five minutes, and not recorded in the revision history. In theory, this would also apply to <2k users - but they have to get their edits *approved*, so it's harder to make two to the same post within five minutes.