# How to resume 'on hold' question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

[How can I use a combination of Scala, Groovy, and Java code with Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760801/can-i-use-scala-or-groovy-for-android-studio-development)

I don't know what to do to unfreeze my question, ask again?

Comment: You should try to reword the question (by [editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)) to fit the rules in the help center, as mentioned in the grey box that notifies you the question is on hold. Are you unclear on why the question was considered primarily opinion based?

Comment: Your question as it currently stands isn't the sort of question appropriate for Stack Overflow.  You're asking for essentially a guide to how to do something; I don't entirely agree with the reason (Off Topic would be better for the content of the question) but either way, not appropriate here.  You're welcome to attempt to use scala or groovy, and ask questions about specific issues you have, but the question currently isn't appropriate.

Comment: The question's title might not help convey the apparent actual question.  Maybe if you rephrased it as "How can I combine Java code with Groovy or Scala code in Android Studio" you could gain some "reopen" votes.

Comment: @Asad thank you for your advise, I'm confuse about the rules after have been reading for a few times. Have changed the question make it more concrete, I'll try reword the question's title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't ask your question again, it will just be closed as a duplicate of the one you've already posted.

Instead, **edit** your existing question to fix the problems that have been pointed out, both in the comments and in the close reason. This is the first step to getting your question taken out of "on hold".

Whenever you edit your question, it will automatically be added to a queue to be reviewed by users who can vote to re-open it. If you've fixed the issues, it will usually get re-opened fairly quickly.

Keep in mind that it's not enough to just make it less opinion-based—it must also be on-topic, as defined in the Help Center:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)