# Why are unicorns playing with tags?

Tags: support, tags, review, review-audits, unicorns

It was a nice day in the close queue, until I found **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3669711)**.
At first, I thought it was mis-tagged since I was filtering on [java](/questions/tagged/java) and the question was about `std::function<T()>` (I know that Java generics are not that weird, despite [many people being confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-sharp-and-java-and-templates-i) about them) .

[image: enter image description here 0_0]

When I tried to edit the question, I found that it **was not** tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java).

[image: ZOMG]

Verily, [it had never ever](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20612774/revisions) been tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java).

## Why are unicorns playing with tags?

Comment: Clearly unicorns now have the power to give the STL to other languages.  Next in line: BASIC.

Comment: This should also be tagged with [unicorns] (yes, it's an actual tag).

Comment: @Jamal done. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like the review you linked to was a review audit...

I've found when I'm going through the close vote review queue with a tag filter, review audits will have the tag I'm filtering on added/substituted in order to make the post look like it matched my filter.

Otherwise, it would be a dead giveaway that a post is an audit if the post doesn't match the tag filter you have set. (It may still be a giveaway that the post doesn't seem to be about your filtered tag, but at least that meant you attempted to read the post.)

Comment: That makes sense... So unicorns are playing with tags by design...

Comment: @Javier Further proof there are unicorns in the system... :)

Comment: So... [[meta-tag:status-unicorns]]?

Comment: [status-unicorns-by-design]

Comment: We should just make [tag:status-bydesign] a synonym for [tag:status-unicorns]. Everything the unicorns do is by design.

Comment: What if the user's action is to remove the tag?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I believe that just clicking on "Edit" causes you to fail the review audit. Not ideal...

Answer (score 7):

Most likely an audit -- these have different tags. Due to limitations of the audit system, they can't actually filter for tags, so they just slap on your tags onto the question. Also, note the discrepancy between the vote counts.

Comment: Still, it'd be nice if these types of review audits were able to test for edits other than what would have been a "removing this tag; the question has nothing to do with it". I had a audit a while back that tacked on java to a haskell question.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but perhaps Yakk accidentally edited in the java tag, realized that he had made a unicorn-grade mistake, and quickly fixed it within the [5 minute grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/191410). You were unfortunate (lucky?) enough to see evidence of a mistYakke during that very brief period in which it existed.

Congratulations.

Comment: No, the other guys got it right - this is an audit, and it'd be a pretty poor audit if it didn't respect your tag filter in some fashion.

Comment: @9Shogsa-Shogging did you not read this guy's display name? "secret _unicorn_ gremlins"?? He's clearly a unicorn trying to hide the blame.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Hey... don't be [disrespectful to the gremlins](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/191410/secret-unicorn-gremlins)!