# Changing a question URL leads to a fully functioning edit page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits

I would like to report a simple, but essential bug.

For example, this link:

[How to get the current date and time in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470617/get-current-date-and-time-in-php)

Make some edit to the URL:

'questions' => 'posts'

'get-current-date-and-time-in-php' => 'edit'

So, it becomes:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/470617/edit

Ensure all required fields are filled then click submit.

Voila! Successfully edited.

I don't know if it's really a bug or I just misunderstand how this site works, but I think it's not good.

Comment: Please explain why you think this is a bug and a problem? You do know you can simply click the "edit" link in order to get the same result, right?

Comment: Please see: [How does editing work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/307988)

Comment: What I want to know is how you figured that URL structure without knowing how edits work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it just isn't a bug in any way.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for late reply, but somehow now it's all good. I got banned after I tried to edit someone question. Previously when I posted this question, I could successfully edit someone question that it should not my priviledge to do it. So, this issue is surely closed. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 9):

> I don't know if its really a bug or I just misunderstand how this site works

This is certainly how this site works. This is by design.

> but I think its not good

We think it is very good. Can you explain why you think differently?

Comment: Somehow I couldn't found the same issue like I got it right before I posted this question. Now I got banned for editing other question which is not my priviledge, and that's not what I got when I posted this question. Sorry for late reply, good to see it now works fine. Thanks @Oded.