# "edit your question" link on author-only guidance on duplicate questions has wrong URL on sites other than Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, post-notices, broken-link

When a question is closed as duplicate, the post owner has their own guidance to edit their question. The guidance also include "edit your question" link.

[image]

The link is supposed to redirect to `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work`. However, clicking the link on Android.SE redirects to [Is there any way to launch an app (and keep the screen on) when a Galaxy Nexus is docked?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/is-there-any-way-to-launch-an-app-and-keep-the-screen-on-when-a-galaxy-nexus-i), which is **Android.SE with Post ID #21788**.

Checking the URL, it's listed as `https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work` (correct slug, wrong domain).

---

Note: the canonical FAQ was posted (migrated from SO) here long before the Meta.SO-Meta.SE split, when this site was known as Meta.SO. To avoid breaking old pre-split `meta.stackoverflow.com` links, the new Meta.SO started post IDs at 250000 and links to posts with lower IDs redirect back here. Due to this redirect, questions closed on Meta.SO and Meta.SE will redirect to the correct canonical FAQ.

Comment: Big bug, very confusing to question askers network wide. Brought up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420595 (see comments)

Comment: @SamuelLiew sadly size doesn't matter, even with bugs. We can only hope a developer will see this at some point and fix it. That said, this does justify pinging a dev in chat, if you have one roaming around in the TL. :)

Comment: TL = [Teachers' Lounge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/teachers-lounge/info)

Comment: ...Strange indeed. I can confirm this by looking at one of my [RPG.SE] questions closed as a dupe as well. I've forwarded this issue to the devs.

Comment: I'm on it and plan to have a fix for it either today or Monday

Comment: Isn't it more practical if it were to redirect to the edit page of the question at hand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great catch, this bug is now fixed. It was generating a question link from that site's context instead of explicitly Meta Stack Exchange's site context. We normally test in a local Meta Stack Exchange environment, so it was really easy for us to miss.

Comment: Is this the source of past bugs where help center articles consisted of absolute links to Meta.SE copies of other help center articles instead of relative links to the site's copies of the same pages?

Comment: I don't expect that to be the case, we manage most help center articles differently.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: No, I think any errors of that kind are just a result of a staff member (at some point) using the absolute link, rather than thinking to use a relative one. Sometimes folks make that mistake because the network-wide versions of Help Center pages are centrally edited from MSE's Help Center.